# Dynamic view with swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to make a dynamic view to answer some questions. Those questions are created from my back office, ant the next question depends on the current user answer. So I have to build my view as things progress.

Here is a example :

First Question :

```
Are you alive ? :  |      Are you sure ?
                   |
YES/NO (no chosen) |        YES/NO
```

I made a subview with the different type of question, and a container view to embed the path like that :

[image]

Here is the code of my container View, the white block is embed in a Scrollview

```
    @ObservedObject var VM:SurveyBrowserViewModel

    @State private var offsetX:CGFloat = 0
    @State private var opacity:Double = 1
    @State var myView:AnyView = AnyView(EmptyView())
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Image("background_survey_canyon")
                .resizable()
            backgroundTriangle
                .opacity(0.65)
            ScrollView(showsIndicators:false){
                myView
                    .padding(.top, 55 + safeAreaTop)
                    .padding(.bottom, 60 + safeAreaBottom)
                    .offset(x : offsetX , y: 0)
                    .opacity(opacity)
                    .onReceive(VM.nextQuestionPassthrough) { (v) in
                        self.myView = v
                    }
                .onReceive(VM.nextQuestionValuePassthrough) { (v) in
                    self.offsetX = v
                    self.opacity = 0
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        self.offsetX = 0
                        self.opacity = 1
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
```

and here is the viewModel section which updates the View state, current question is the question which needs to be displayed according the good type.

```
    var nextQuestionPassthrough = PassthroughSubject<AnyView,Never>()
    /// Get The good view to match the correct question tyoe
    /// - Parameter answerSelected: Binding bool to hide/show next button  visibility
    private func getGoodView(){
        guard (currentQuestion != nil) else { nextQuestionPassthrough.send(AnyView(EmptyView())); return }
        switch QuestionType.intToQuestionType(value: currentQuestion!.type!){
        case .YesOrNo :
            if currentQuestionViewModel == nil{
                currentQuestionViewModel = YesNoQuestionViewModel(question: currentQuestion!,temporaryId: temporaryId)
            }
            nextQuestionPassthrough.send(AnyView(YesNoQuestionView(VM: currentQuestionViewModel as! YesNoQuestionViewModel,answerSelected: nextViewState! )))
        }
    }
```

I've tried different way to achieve what I'm expecting :

- I want a animation like a auto scroll coming form right to left, but it's cosmetic and it's not my main problem.

My problem is that when i send view from the nextQuestionPassthrough the init section from my new view is called but not the appear one. So all state are saved as we can see on the picture ( yes and no answer are two @State set to false at initialization but stay selected when I send the new view. I tried several ideas, like a published view instead of a @State but the behavior is the same.

I'm thinking about a new approch, with my container embed two views to make the good animation and the good life cycle ( init then appear )

Has anyone ever studied this problem or done something similar?

Comment: As soon as I see SwiftUI View outside of `ViewBuilder` pass, in this case `@State var myView:AnyView` I understand that there is no reason to see further... just redesign to follow SwiftUI concept, ie. views in view, models in model, view model between them, in short MVVM, and all will work.

Comment: I agree with you, but have you a solution for me, or did you tried it, or just a suggestion ?